# Document Client Exception Incorrect Error Status Code

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

While testing DocumentDb stored procedures I intentionally created a document with a duplicate id so that I can observe the DocumentClientException.  According to the documentation at http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html#.ErrorCodes I was expecting the exception to have a 409 status code indicating Conflict.

The stored procedure code is as follows:

```
isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, 
        duplicateIdDoc,
        { disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true },
        function(err, createdDoc, options){
            if (err) throw err;  // Rollback                      
        });
```

I do receive an exception but the error code is 400 (BadRequest).  The message text indicates the correct problem.  A resource with the specified id or name already exists.

"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"Resource with specified id or name already exists\\"]}\r\nStack trace: Error: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"Resource with specified id or name already exists\\"]}\n   at Anonymous function (duplicateIdTest.js:56:26)\n   at Anonymous function (duplicateIdTest.js:685:29)\"]}\r\nActivityId: 886230cf-8d49-433e-845f-8cc7c2ae486d, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/32782613-7101-4924-97b0-604052a6723b/partitions/be6c2ec8-130c-4596-90a2-b1807977dd0b/replicas/131240065159522367p"

Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All errors thrown inside stored procedures are propagated as `400 (BadRequest)`. However, individual calls to the database like `createDocument` return the same error codes as the REST API.

For example, you can check the value of `err.code === 409` inside your callback to validate that `crateDocument` failed due to a conflict. amd not something else.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems a little strange but am able to get the actual code using the following `if (err) throw new Error('CODE' + err.number + 'CODE');` and using Regex to split it out of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

err.code wouldn't work, Use err.number in your callback to handle known exception

Ex: err.number === 409 for conflict